# Automate a process to copy certain parts of the CSV into a new CSV file

Tags: .net, csv, automation, export-to-csv

Whats the best way to automate the process of taking a CSV file, editing/copying some contents of the file into another CSV file?

Ideally, there is a folder with 1000s of CSVs that need to be modified in the same way. Hence the automation. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply you can read csv file fields and change / editing and save those all fields into another csv file.

For example, if I have one csv file (user.csv) and this file contains 2 columns `username` and `password` and I want to update those fields, the coding is here:

```
String text = null;
string filename="user.csv";
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
            DataInputStream myInput = new DataInputStream(fis);
            while ((text = myInput.readLine()) != null) {
                // System.out.println(text);

                String[] strar = text.split(",");
                String username = strar[0];
                String password = strar[1];
              // so here you can update both username and password and save into another 
csv file
  string write=username +","+password ;
WriteToCsv(write);

                    }
 } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
    enter code here

//save into csv file here
 public static synchronized void WriteToCsv(String s) {
        PrintWriter pw = null;
        try {
            File f = new File(newfile);
            pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(f, true));
            pw.println(s);
            pw.flush();
            pw.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            pw.close();
        }
    }
```